# WSL2 Tensorflow GPU not getting found when using Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: tensorflow

I followed the instructions from [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2) to install Tensorflow.
I downloaded the necessary CUDA drivers from the following [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local).
I installed the necessary and latest NVIDIA Drivers for my GPU as well.
Then, I installed Miniconda3 and setup an environment with all the necessary Tensorflow libraries.
When I was done, I ran some test:

1. Called the nvidia-smi:
   [image: Nvidia SMI Report]
2. Called python3 and printed the GPU report from the console:

```
"python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('Number of GPUs: ', len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"
```

and received the following report:

```
TensorFlow version: 2.13.0  | GPU:  [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

However, When I used Visual Studio code with WSL2 with Jupyter Notebook, the report failed to discover the GPU:

```
TensorFlow version: 2.13.0  | GPU:  []
```

I am not sure how to get the GPU recognized in WSL2.  The GPU does get discovered with Pytorch.